# Group the list based on start and end condition rules

Tags: python-3.x, list, group-by

I have an input list below.

input_list = `[[['A', 'bold', 1], ['B', 'notbold', 2], ['C', 'bold', 3], ['D', 'notbold', 4]], [['A', 'bold', 7], ['E', 'notbold', 8], ['K', 'notbold', 9], ['F', 'notbold', 10], ['C', 'bold', 11], ['N', 'notbold', 12], ['T', 'notbold', 13]], [['A', 'bold', 14], ['J', 'notbold', 15], ['X', 'notbold', 16], ['V', 'notbold', 17], ['C', 'bold', 18], ['M', 'notbold', 19]], [['A', 'bold', 35]]]`

My expected output is:

```
    [[['A', 'bold', 1], ['B', 'notbold', 2], ['C', 'bold', 3], ['D', 'notbold', 4]], 
 [['A', 'bold', 7], ['E', 'notbold', 8], ['K', 'notbold', 9], ['F', 'notbold', 10], ['C', 'bold', 11], ['N', 'notbold', 12], ['T', 'notbold', 13]], 
 [['A', 'bold', 14], ['J', 'notbold', 15], ['X', 'notbold', 16], ['V', 'notbold', 17], ['C', 'bold', 18], ['M', 'notbold', 19]], [['A', 'bold', 35]]]
```

Output is Based on below conditions:

1. Start a group when an item ['A', 'bold'] is encountered.
2. Continue adding items to the group until a ['C', 'bold'] is found.
3. But there should not be some more ['A', 'bold'] between start ['A', 'bold'] and ['C', 'bold']
   Once a ['C', 'bold'] has been found, continue adding items until another 'bold' item other than ['C', 'bold'] is encountered, at which point the group is closed and the 'bold' item is excluded from the group.

I found similar code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353862/how-to-create-sublists-from-list-based-on-start-and-end-elements).

I wrote the below code and want to make it simpler.

```
def group_data(input_list):
    groups = []
    current_group = []
    found_a = False
    found_c = False

    for index, item in enumerate(input_list):
        # start of group
        if item == ['A', 'bold']:
            if not found_a:
                found_a = True
                if current_group:  # if a previous group is pending, append it to groups
                    groups.append(current_group)
                current_group = [item+[index]]
            else:  # restart the group
                current_group = [item+[index]]
                found_c = False
        # end condition
        elif found_a and item[1] == 'bold':
            if item == ['C', 'bold']:
                found_c = True
                current_group.append(item+[index])
                groups.append(current_group)
            elif found_c:  # end of group
                current_group.append(item+[index])
                groups.append(current_group)
                current_group = []
                found_a = False
                found_c = False
        # adding other elements
        elif found_a:
            current_group.append(item+[index])

    if current_group:  # if there's still a pending group at the end
        groups.append(current_group)

    return groups
```